# Firestore rule get() work in the simulator but not in the app

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to make a firestore rule that will check if the user is the owner of the "parent" collection.

I have a structure like this:

```
   collection of -> [Diets]
        document -> (owner : "owner")
                      |
   subCollection -> [Food]
        document -> (name : "Carrot")
```

I would like to have the possibility to read and write documents in a [Food] subcollection using the doc properties of a [Diet] document.

This version works, but it checks only for the requested source, it doesn't always check the [Diet].

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents{
        match /diets/{id}/{id2=**} {
            allow read, write: if resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;
        }
    }
}
```

This version will not work even when the parent (the Diet doc itself) is the requested source.
Isn't this solution supposed to be the same as the previous one while checking a DOC inside diets?

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents{
        match /diets/{id}/{id2=**} {
            allow read, write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/diets/$(id)).data.owner == request.auth.uid;
        }
    }
}
```

Isn't this solution supposed to work the same as the previous one while checking a Diet document?

It works in the simulator, and everything seems fine, even when requesting subcollections documents, but I got the **"FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions"** error in my app.

This is the code of my app.

```
firebase.firestore().collection("diets").where("owner", "==", this.userID).get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        console.log(doc);
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());    
    });
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
});
```

Comment: did you find a solution for your problem? It seems i have a very similar one.

Comment: i finally found a workaround, maybe it helps you too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63022358/5155810

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console simulator can only simulate individual document gets.  It currently can't simulate collection queries, which are handled differently.

The problem you're running into is that [security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query).  I strongly suggest reading that documentation, and [this article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/what-does-it-mean-that-firestore-security-rules-are-not-filters-68ec14f3d003).  The reason why your first rule works is because the rule can very easily check that your query's filter matches that constraints in the rule for all possible documents returned.  It is impossible for the query to ever ask for anything more than the rule clearly allows.  However, when you involve `get()`, the rule will not evaluate that `get()` for each document in the collection, as that would be extremely slow with large collections.  **It will not attempt to filter the documents by checking the result of a `get()` on each one.**

The rule works for individual document gets because there is no filtering involved - just a single document check - which is well within the capabilities of the rule at massive scale.

Again, the trick is to see this from the point of view of the rules at massive scale.  If you have billions of documents in a collection, checking each one individually would simply not perform well at all, so the rule simply rejects it.  The rule can only really check that the query filters match the specific constraints of the rule without checking each document.

Comment: How does this answer relate to the question? I can't see where the author intends to filter the sub collection.