# nested firebase-firestore rules: owner id within parent document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I can't get these rules to work:
I've got a collection with projects, which all have an owner. The owner should be allowed to read/write his projects and the subcollection working_copies as well.

This implementation succesfully grants reading the project, but fails (**Missing or insufficient permissions**) when reading a working_copy from the sub collection. I suspect it tries to find an owner within the sub-document.

```
service cloud.firestore {

  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /projects/{projectId} {
      allow read, write: if 
        resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid;

      match /working_copies/{doc} {
        allow read, write: if true;
      }

  }
}
```

I've also tried using this condition either in the project path or in the working_copies path, but it both fails as well:

```
    get(/databases/$(database)/documents/projects/$(projectId)).data.owner == request.auth.uid
```

Everything above also fails when i use a recursive wildcard for nesting:

```
match /projects/{projectId=**} {
   ...
```

The strange thing is, i think the first version used to work until some days ago.

I use angular/angularfire and call the requests like  this:

```
 this.db.collection('projects').doc('3279').collection<ProjectData>('working_copies').valueChanges().pipe(...
```

In the rules simulator it's green lighted though.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the (minimal, standalone) code of the failing read?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen this.db.collection('projects').doc('3279').collection<ProjectData>('working_copies').valueChanges().pipe(...

Comment: That looks fine at first glance. Can you edit it *into* your question, and then also add the exact/complete error message you get?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Done. It doesn't give away more than 'Missing or insufficient permissions'

Comment: Hmmm.... I don't immediately what's going wrong here. I hope somebody else spots it.

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found a workaround:

```
!('owner' in resource.data) || resource.data.owner == request.auth.uid
```

This makes it accept that the child document doesn't provide the owner once more. So it seems, when nesting rules, the parent rules are also applied to child documents.

Comment: This makes me wonder if ```!('owner' in resource.data)``` wont always be true. I tried a few tests since I had a similar problem and it seems resource is only returning the data in the parent. **EDIT**: Nope you are correct. I was able to prove that it does read the child. Thanks for posting this.